# Support for sharing the SAML login session to different vendor in IOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, authentication, saml, saml-2.0

We have a App A and we use SAML as login. Requirement is to share same SAML session into other vendor apps from our app A. Not sure how to achieve it. Any pointers will of great help. Please let me know if the question is not proper.

Thank you in advance.

Prabhakar.

Comment: SAML audience should be taken into account if sharing information with entities the IdP doesn't know about. The IdP releases to AppA, not any other vendor apps AppA knows about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778156/recipient-vs-audience-in-saml-2-0

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a typical use case for SAML SSO.
Today, as you say you are using SAML as login, I guess you have a SAML Identity Provider that App A send user to for authentication.

What you need to do is to set up the vendor apps to use that same IdP to also authenticate users with. If the user is already authenticated in another app the user will not need to sign in again and will be sent back the the requesting app immediately without needing to authenticate.

Comment: IOS doesn't allow passing of cookies or tokens to other app, due to security reasons. Not sure how to get around that.